# Support with express webpack and babel on this project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to add Express to this site, but I get this error when running my script `npm run webpack`:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 11:3
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no
loaders are configured to process this file.
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    |
    | ReactDOM.render(
    >    <ProductProvider>
    |       <Router>
    |           <App />
```

> **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "public",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

> **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "react-css-modules", 
      { 
        "option": "value" 
      } 
    ]
  ]
}
```

I should expect this to work but I keep getting that error. I need help with this. I'm new to this. I tried doing everything I know, but it keeps saying that error.

Comment: What does `./src/index.js` contain? Is it the entry point to your React code? Are you trying to compile your Express app with Webpack?

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import {ProductProvider} from './context';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(
   <ProductProvider>
      <Router>
          <App />
      </Router>
  </ProductProvider>,
 document.getElementById('root'));

this is what the index.js contain , yes im trying to compile express app with webpack

Comment: Can you confirm that you have installed `babel-loader` and its presets?

Comment: yes i have installed it

Comment: The error is basically Webpack stating that it does not understand JSX. `babel-loader` along with `@babel/core` and the presets in your `.babelrc` should be able to compile the JSX code. At this point, Express is irrelevant to your error. Can you post your `package.json`?